# Use stdlib and rand with Node native module (node-gyp)

Tags: c++, node.js, node-gyp, gyp, node-addon-api

This is just an example of the problem.

Let's say I have `utils.cc`

```cc
#include "../headers/utils/utils.h"

double sum()
{
    double result = 1 + 1;
    return result;
}

double multisum(int n)
{
    double result = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        result += rand();
    }
    return result;
}
```

and this file that uses it

```cc
#include "../headers/modules/sum.h"
#include "../headers/utils.h"

/* HELPERS DECLARATION */

static void ReturnResult(int result, const FunctionCallbackInfo<Value> &args);

/* EXPORTED IMPLEMENTATION */

void Sum(const FunctionCallbackInfo<Value> &args)
{
    double result = sum();
    ReturnResult(result, args);
}
void Multisum1e7(const FunctionCallbackInfo<Value> &args)
{
    int result = multisum(1e7);
    ReturnResult(result, args);
}

/* HELPERS IMPLEMENTATION */

static void ReturnResult(double result, const FunctionCallbackInfo<Value> &args)
{
    Isolate *isolate = args.GetIsolate();
    args.GetReturnValue().Set(Number::New(isolate, result));
}
```

These functions are then exported with `<node.h>`.

The problem is in the `rand()` function. The code compiles (I have included stdlib in the code) and this is the `binding.gyp`:

```json
{
  "targets": [
    {
      "target_name": "addon",
      "sources": [
        "addon/main.cc",
        "addon/utils.cc",
        "addon/modules/sum.cc"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

But at runtime I got this error:

```
node: symbol lookup error: /xxx/build/Release/addon.node: undefined symbol: _ZL12ReturnResultiRKN2v820FunctionCallbackInfoINS_5ValueEEE
```

That disappears if I don't use `rand()`;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forward declare your helper function like this:

```
static void ReturnResult(int result, const FunctionCallbackInfo<Value> &args);
//                       ^^^
```

but then implement it like this:

```
static void ReturnResult(double result, const FunctionCallbackInfo<Value> &args)
//                       ^^^^^^
```

So fix whichever one is wrong and your problem should go away.

---

You might like to know about [demangler.com](http://demangler.com).  That would have told you that the mangled symbol in your linker error corresponds to:

`ReturnResult(int, v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value> const&)`

which I imagine would have been helpful.

Comment: Sorry for the stupid question, I am not so good with C. Why wasn't there a compilation error? Is it because the compiler looks only at the `.h` version and when it is run, there is a problem because the linked binary does not match that "expectations"?